# CopyEnhMetaFile() is not releasing the handle even if DeleteEnhMetaFile() is called

Tags: visual-c++

I have a sample code which copies one metafile to another location. First time it is succeeding but subsequent trials fails saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Please see my code

HENHMETAFILE hemf = GetEnhMetaFile(L"C:\Temp\MyMeta.emf");

CopyEnhMetaFile(hemf, L"C:\Temp\MyMetaCopy.emf"))

DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);

Comment: Got the reason! We need to delete the handle returned by CopyEnhMetaFile()

Comment: How to delete it?