# ZedGraph doesn't dispose emf file after create it

Tags: c#, dispose, zedgraph, intptr

I have this code below:

```
static internal bool SaveEnhMetafileToFile(Metafile mf, string fileName)
{
  bool bResult = false;
    IntPtr hEMF;
    hEMF = mf.GetHenhmetafile(); // invalidates mf 
    if (!hEMF.Equals(new IntPtr(0)))
    {
        StringBuilder tempName = new StringBuilder(fileName);
        CopyEnhMetaFile(hEMF, tempName);
        DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF);

   }
    return bResult;
}
```

When `CopyEnhMetaFile(hEMF, tempName);` is called, the picture is created but after calling `DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF);` function I cannot delete the picture because it is used by my program (`vshost.exe`). 
The program is created in C#

Comment: Is this the reason : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869578/copyenhmetafile-is-not-releasing-the-handle-even-if-deleteenhmetafile-is-cal

Comment: Probably, but in that link does not say how to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the link I posted - you need to delete the handle created by CopyEnhMetaFile :

```
static internal bool SaveEnhMetafileToFile(Metafile mf, string fileName)
{
  bool bResult = false;
  IntPtr hEMF;
  hEMF = mf.GetHenhmetafile(); // invalidates mf 
  if (!hEMF.Equals(new IntPtr(0)))
  {
    StringBuilder tempName = new StringBuilder(fileName);
    IntPtr hCopyEMF = CopyEnhMetaFile(hEMF, tempName.ToString());
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hCopyEMF);
    DeleteEnhMetaFile(hEMF);
  }
return bResult;
}
```